# Provide multiple SendCompleted callbacks to SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous-programming

I have an `Email` class that has a `Send` method that optionally takes an `SmtpClient` and sends an email asynchronously using `SendAsync`. If no `SmtpClient` is supplied to this method, it instantiates a default `SmtpClient` and uses that to send the email. Inside the `Send` function, I provide a [`SendCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted.aspx) callback which disposes of the `MailMessage` and the default `SmtpClient` if one was not supplied to the method.

**So when I am supplying the `SmtpClient`, how do I go about disposing it?**

I can't dispose of it inside `Send` because it may be used for sending other emails, plus I figure it's the responsibility of the thing that instantiated the passed in `SmtpClient` to dispose of it again. Is it possible to add multiple `SendCompleted` callbacks to the `SmtpClient` that run after each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major ways of going about destroying your `SmtpClient` objects.

1. The `SmtpClient` manages its own lifetime (i.e. destroys itself when the time comes). This is easiest if each `SmtpClient` is used for only one email, but it can be made to work for multiple, if `SmtpClient` knows how many emails it sent and it can be guaranteed that the `SendCompleted` callback is invoked a corresponding number of times.
2. An outside component manages the lifetime of `SmtpClient` (this can be the object that created `SmtpClient` or some other object). In this case, the `SmtpClient` needs to inform the object responsible for managing its lifetime about the `SendCompleted` callback being invoked. This is usually done by invoking a callback on that object from within `SendCompleted`.

Comment: Both of these options require that you be able to add multiple SendCompleted callbacks. Is this possible?

Comment: @ajbeaven: In general, it should be possible unless the documentation explicitly forbids this.